# Why have this answer deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I came across this question : [What is the name of the “-->” operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/2307070), scrolled down a lot to read answers and find [this gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909176/2307070):

[image]

This answer is accurate, taught me something and was highly up-voted. There is nothing in the comment history that seems to arm anyone, I didn't find any discussion about it on meta...

So why does it have been deleted?

Comment: Probably because we hate fun here. (Either that, or because it doesn't answer the question at all - doesn't even attempt to. It just provides even more confusing syntax.)

Comment: There are *a lot* of deleted answers under this post. Why single out this one?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi because this is the first one that have been shown to me, it have 1k upvotes

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure "being clever with backslashes" warrants 1051 upvotes. Then again, that question was absurdly popular (402,636 views), so it's not the worse that could happen.

Comment: In all honesty, that whole question could simple go down the drain. It's an amusing confusion. Not much more than that.

Comment: probably a historical lock then. Its still a decent read for those who have mastered the lost art of paying attention.

Comment: It does not answer the question at all, it is just another "hey, I've got a funny one as well" post.  Which of course fails the most basic requirement of an answer.  Belongs in a blog.

Comment: I believe it has been archived. Since I too could not find it.

Comment: Because it doesn't even attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was not an answer. The question asked what the `-->` operator was called, whether it was defined in the standard, and where it came from. You could possibly stretch the question to asking what the operator *does* and how it works.

The answer you linked to doesn't actually answer *any* of those questions. Rather, it is a "me too"-style contribution, suggesting another way to write obfuscated code by the clever use of line-continuation characters.

The answer itself even admits that it isn't an answer, starting out as it does with "or for something completely different." Yeah, completely different from the question everyone else is talking about. Not a good way to start an answer if you want it to stick around.

> This answer is accurate

I don't know what you mean by this. We've established it isn't an answer to the question, so you must be asserting that it is *technically* accurate, in the sense that the syntax does what is advertised. That may well be true, but it is equally true that they sell pinto beans by the pound at the grocery store. That does not an answer make.

> taught me something

Let's hope to God not. I doubt you have or ever will see code like this in the wild, so it's not like it is useful to be able to understand what it does. The only possible thing it could have "taught" you is how to write code like this yourself. Which is something you should never do. It fails the "useful" test here, as well.

> was highly up-voted

Yeah, so it was. Unfortunately, people will upvote any damn thing, especially if it is clever, funny, and understandable by everyone. The number of upvotes on the answer also has to be evaluated relative to the question, which has gotten a ridiculous number of votes itself, far more than anyone would have ever reasonably expected. That isn't really a good argument for keeping it around, although it does suggest that it would have been popular as a blog post.

It fails the most basic of tests that we apply to answers—does this provide an answer to the question—and, as such, was deleted by a moderator. There have been a bunch of other, similar, not-an-answer "answers" to that same question deleted. This is [the trouble with popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/).

Comment: no need to refer Wikipedia when we've got  [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) article at SO blog: "we discovered that these posts... truly start to drown out everything else on the site... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..."